# My app crashes after starting activity with scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, scrollview

I have a problem with an Android application. In the app there is an xml file which contains a RelativeLayout and inside a Scroll view. Inside the scrollview there some images which I want to display. The problem is that when there are 3 ImageView inside the scrollview the activity and the xml page works fine but ,when I add the 4th ImageView , application crashes when I start the activity.

I am posting the code below, the problem occurs when the 4th ImageView is added.  Any ideas?

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Double_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/trouble" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Secret_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Double_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/secret" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kidnap_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/Secret_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/kidnap" />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/kidnap2_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/kidnap_image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/kidnap2" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

NOTE: The activity which is connected with this xml file doesn't have any functionality.

Here is the Activity class connected with the above xml.

```
package com.example.thomas.firstcue;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RoomsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rooms);
    }
}
```

I start the activity from Main through a button click and the function StartActivity

```
  rooms_but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startActivity(intentrooms);

        }

    });
```

The application starts normally on phone but when I am pressing the button to Start the activity , the app crashes.
[On phone error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D1Ge.jpg)

Comment: add crash log, and also add your java class

Comment: post your stack trace.. my best guess is that `outOfMemoryError` because of high resolution images..

Comment: is your 4th image have (v24) in drawble folder like **kidnap.png(v24)** ?

Comment: @Milan is right first paste your error log

Comment: I consider your comments and I made the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility of crashing app is your 4th image which reside in `drawable` have `v24` like  `kidnap.png(v24)`

so first delete this image from drawable folder(..\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24) and again paste it in `drawable`(..\app\src\main\res\drawable) folder with only `kidnap.png`